# How to have response message from jax-rs after put operation

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

i'm using jersey to add an object to a db:

Server side:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response sendMail(Message m) {
    boolean result = db.sendMessage(m);
    return Response.status(201).entity(result?"sent":"notsent").build();
}
```

Client side:

```
public void send(Message m){
        service.path("rest").path("send").accept(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(m);

}
```

How can i get from client the message "sent" or "notsent" ?? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sending plain string, not XML, so you should use media type text/plain. To receive the string on the client side, you can use:

```
String result = webResource.accept("text/plain").put(m, String.class);
```